# Static noise at gig that has no electrical grounding in the building?

Tags: guitar

How do I stop the static noise that comes from my electric guitar and amp while I am playing at a gig that has no electrical grounding in the building?

Comment: I won't play a venue that has improperly wired electrical service. As much as I love music, it's not worth my life or the lives of my band mates.

Comment: Still makes me wonder, in this day & age, what territories would not just close down any building which wasn't properly earthed :/

Comment: Out of interest, where is this gig venue?

Comment: @Tetsujin is is pretty common in Philadelphia (for example) for gigs to be in spaces not zoned or properly permitted as music venues, and in many cases they may even be "squats."

Answer (score 6):

Easy answer! You take your guitar,amp,etc., and go home! Playing with unsafe electricity? I'd rather play in a snake pit. Often you only get one chance, after which you could be playing a harp instead. And I don't mean one you suck and blow.

Seriously (and the above para. is serious) A lot of guitar gear has warning signs not to lift the earth. They're there for a good reason. Safety says that the chassis of amps, which are directly connected to any metal parts on guitars, mics, etc. must have a direct line to earth. Yes, I know some players disconnect earth, often to get rid of hum, but were there to be a serious wiring problem in their gear, the first they would know about it would be the last.

Comment: Indeed.  What country is this building located in?